# Transfer InputStream between 2 servers

Tags: java, jersey, microservices

I have the following code that takes an `InputStream` and sends it to another server:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

MultipartBody mpb = new MultipartBody(
        new Attachment(
                "file",
                uploadedInputStream,
                new ContentDisposition("file=test.pdf")
        )
);

Response response = client.target(url)
        .request(APPLICATION_JSON)
        .post(Entity.entity(mpb, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE), Response.class);
```

and in the second server i have this api:

```
public String uploadFile(
    @Context HttpServletRequest request,
    @PathParam("name") String fileName,
    @PathParam("type") int type,
    @PathParam("userIdentifier") String userId,
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail
)
{
    return null;
}
```

and I am getting error 400.

when I am taking out the `@FormDataParam` of the `InputStream` and the `FormDataContentDisposition`.

everything is ok and I am getting a success response.

Answer (score 0):

So, I didn't found any solution, so instead of sending the file as an attachment, I send him as a byte.
this is how I did it:

the first server:

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(uploadedInputStream);

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

Invocation.Builder request = client.target(url)
        .request(APPLICATION_JSON);
Response response = request.post(Entity.entity(bytes, APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE), Response.class);
```

the second that receives the file:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("")
public IBlResult<String> uploadFile(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
                                    @PathParam("name") String fileName,
                                    @PathParam("type") int type,
                                    @PathParam("userIdentifier") int userId,
                                    byte[] file
)
{
    return null;
}
```